# Test if an expression is a Function?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

How would a function `FunctionQ` look like, maybe in a way I can even specify the number of arguments allowed?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question.  Do you mean that you want to write a function FunctionQ[input_] which returns True if input is a function, false otherwise ?  What form does input take ?

Comment: @Mark: The first question I'd answer with Yes. The form the input would take is a Mathematica expression...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I really feel bad posting after Simon and Daniel, but their codes fail on non-functions which are not symbols. Checking for that and adding a check for builtins via `NumericFunction`, as suggested by Simon, we arrive at something like

```
FunctionQ[_Function | _InterpolatingFunction | _CompiledFunction] = True;
FunctionQ[f_Symbol] := Or[
  DownValues[f] =!= {}, 
  MemberQ[ Attributes[f], NumericFunction ]]
FunctionQ[_] = False;
```

which should work in some (sigh) real-world cases

```
In[17]:= 
FunctionQ/@{Sin,Function[x,3x], Compile[x,3 x],Interpolation[Range[5]],FunctionQ,3x,"a string", 5}
Out[17]= {True,True,True,True,True,False,False,False}
```

If you know the signature of the function you are looking for (i.e. how many arguments and of what type), I would agree with Simon that the way to go is duck typing: `Apply` the function to typical arguments, and look for valid output. Caching might be worthwhile:

```
AlternativeFunctionQ[f_]:=AlternativeFunctionQ[f]=
  With[{TypicalArgs={1.0}},NumericQ[Apply[f,TypicalArgs]]];

In[33]= AlternativeFunctionQ/@{Sin,Function[x,3x], Compile[x, 3x],Interpolation[Range[5]],FunctionQ,3x,"a string", 5}
Out[34]= {True,True,True,True,False,False,False,False}
```

Comment: Definitely don't feel bad! That's SO's MO: build on each other to come up with the best possible answer. Great work on this, btw!

Comment: I was just looking over this again, and I noticed that `FunctionQ` is not found to be a 1 var function by `AlternativeFunctionQ`.  So, while it is effective at finding numerical functions, it cannot find other types.

Comment: @rcollyer: The `AlternativeFunctionQ` was meant as an example: The typical arguments as well as the valid output should be adapted to the case at hand. I guess this is not very elegant from an architecture point of view, but it often fits the bill quite well.

Comment: I love how I can bounce around SO and continue to find new and interesting answers like this. +1 and cheers for SO.

Answer (score 4):

As Daniel said, his test (which probably should read)

```
FunctionQ[x_] := Head[x] === Function || DownValues[x] =!= {}
```

Is quick and dirty.  It will fail for built in functions, e.g. `FunctionQ[Sin]` will return False (Many built-in functions will  be caught by checking for the `Attribute` `NumericFunction`). It will also fail for things like `f[x_][y_]` etc... It should probably also test `UpValues`, `SubValues` and maybe `NValues` (see [here](http://www.verbeia.com/mathematica/tips/HTMLLinks/Tricks_Misc_4.html) for their meanings).

This problem was discussed in this [thread](http://groups.google.com.au/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/6b8c6a826824ff7c/56c51351066fe851). Many useful ideas are in this thread - eg ways to find the number of arguments that some functions can take, but there was no real consensus reached in the discussion.

I think that the best approach is a kind of [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing).  You probably know how many and what type of arguments you want your function to take, so test it with [ValueQ](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ValueQ.html). Then make sure that you catch errors using [Check](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Check.html).

EDIT:
Another comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica [thread](http://groups.google.com.au/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/2027a5cf5715a83f).

Answer (score 2):

Here's something quick and dirty which may do what you need:

```
FunctionQ[x_] := Head[x] == Function || DownValues[x] =!= {}
```