# List all global variables

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, global-variables

As [noted elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166027/list-all-user-defined-variables-functions-in-a-notebook-in-mathematica), you can list all user-defined symbols with this:

```
Names["Global`*"]
```

But I'd like to find just my global variables (I'm in the middle of some hairy debugging), not my function definitions.  Something like this is close:

```
Select[Names["Global`*"], Head@Symbol[#]=!=Symbol && Head@Symbol[#]=!=Function&]
```

But that misses variables whose value is a symbol (perhaps I have `x = Pi`).

I could probably beat that thing into submission but maybe there's a cleaner, more direct way?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If we consider any symbol with an own-value as a "variable", then this will do the trick:

```
ClearAll[variableQ]
variableQ[name_String] := {} =!= ToExpression[name, InputForm, OwnValues]

Select[Names["Global`*"], variableQ]
```

Note that this technique will fail on read-protected symbols and will misidentify some forms of auto-loaded functions.

**Edit 1**

As @Szabolcs points out, the definition of `variableQ` can be simplified if `ValueQ` is used:

```
variableQ[name_String] := ToExpression[name, InputForm, ValueQ]
```

**Edit 2**

As @dreeves points out, it might be desirable to filter out apparent variables whose values are functions, e.g. `f = (#+1)&`:

```
variableQ[name_String] :=
  MatchQ[
    ToExpression[name, InputForm, OwnValues]
  , Except[{} | {_ :> (Function|CompiledFunction)[___]}]
  ]
```

This definition could be easily extended to check for other function-like forms such as interpolating functions, auto-loaded symbols, etc.

Comment: Perfect; thank you! I may also want to exclude functions defined like `f = (#+1&)` which is easy to add a check for (just see whether the Head is Function, like I did in the question). But your solution is what you'd generally want. Thanks again.

Comment: @WReach, @dreeves Related function: `ValueQ`.  It's essentially the same: `variableQ[name_String] := ToExpression[name, InputForm, ValueQ]`

Comment: @Szabolcs Actually, in general  `ValueQ` is not so innocent, since in many cases it leaks evaluation - it evaluates things in the process of testing for a value (I discussed it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599241/checking-if-a-symbol-is-defined/4621562#4621562 in more detail). For `OwnValues` though, it seems to be OK, so my comment is only tangentially relevant to the case at hand.

Comment: @Leonid, I'm aware of that, as it's possible to check the implementation of `ValueQ` (just remove the `ReadProtected` attribute).  Yes, I should have mentioned that `ValueQ` is applicable to any expression, but will only guarantee that it won't evaluate that expression in the case of Symbols (our case).  **EDIT:** I just noticed you present the implementation of `ValueQ` in the post you linked to as well.

Answer (score 1):

One might consider a variable to be a `` Global` `` symbol that does not pass [`FunctionQ`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736942/test-if-an-expression-is-a-function/3748658#3748658).